# Disambiguate the /background tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) is mostly about background processes, but there are also questions about background colors and background images.

I think we should:

- Retag questions about background colors to just [colors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) or [theme](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme) as appropriate.
- Retag questions about background images to [desktop-background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-background).
- Retag any question tagged [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) but not about background processes as appropriate — are there any?
- Rename [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) to [background-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-process) to avoid confusion.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is this really a problem? I couldn't find any background color questions in the last few months. - Maybe it is enough to manually fix those rare cases of misuse.

Comment: Was the wiki except there previously?  Right now it seems very unambiguous to me.  You can't completely stop people from not bothering to read/think.   The real problem is that there are two tags referring to the same thing.  What would help with that is **if mods were notified whenever someone created a new tag** -- I am sure that would catch *most* of this kind of thing from the start, saving the much bigger hassle later and all the dysfunctional events in between.

Comment: @goldilocks The excerpt has only been there for a week (you can check the revision history). In fact, I'd forgotten about it, but reviewing the excerpt suggestion must have been what prompted my meta question. Notifying moderators on each tag creation wouldn't be useful: this isn't something that moderators need to act about. Anyone can monitor newly created tags in the [“new” tab of the Tags page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new), and edit posts that they think are not tagged appropriately.

Comment: Eureka!  Thanks Gilles.  See, I can't even completely stop my *myself* from not bothering to read/think.  Although as a mod, I'd still appreciate more of an alert, so I don't have to remember yet-another-thing-to-check-on-regularly.  I don't think people should be allowed to create tags with no excerpt, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 129 questions tagged [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) only three of which were not about background processes. Presumably you all have been busy retagging, thanks!

I have now

- retagged those three with [wallpaper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper)
- Created a [desktop-background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-background) -> [wallpaper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper) synonym. I did it this way since [wallpaper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper) already existed and it was less disruptive.
- Renamed [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) to [background-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-process).

Answer (score 6):

The word *background* has [many meanings](http://www.memidex.com/background) all of which could conceivably apply to U&L. In addition to your list, *philosophical*, *historical* and *technical backgrounds* abound.

Let it burn.

Comment: Meanings that “conceivably apply” are irrelevant. What matters is meanings that people actually use. If you've found uses of [tag:background] with meanings other than the ones I mentioned, please cite some examples so we can decide what to do about them. Furthermore why do you want to burn the tag? [tag:background-process] is a perfectly well-defined notion, why do you want to eliminate it?

Comment: @Gilles I seem to have explained this badly. I intended to argue that there should be no tag called "background". The existing tags "background-process" and "desktop-background" are perfectly clear and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background) tag clearly talks about background processes. To avoid confusion probably the clearest solution is to rename the tag to `background-process`.

Comment: The description has only been there for a week. It's legitimate, because [tag:background] is *mostly* used for background processes; now we need to do some cleanup.